# Is there a way inserts exit callback function in freeglut (or glut)?

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

In my freeglut project, i have allocated alot of memory, and i have no ways to free that when users close freeglut (or glut) window, any ideas?

Comment: Why bother? Closing your GLUT window the process gets terminated anyway, releasing all allocated resources.

Comment: @datenwolf: i know this is seem stupid but i want do the things in legal ways :-|

Comment: Actually, I had a problem with CUDA because it freed its buffers before my destructors were called, so sometimes you actually need to do it by "your own" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FreeGLUT offers several solutions to that:

1. You can call `glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION)` and `glutLeaveMainLoop()` to make `glutMainLoop()` function return, and then you can free all the memory you want after `glutMainLoop()` call.
2. Instead of calling `glutMainLoop()` you can make your own event loop like this:

   ```
   bool running = true;
   while (running)
   {
       glutMainLoopEvent();
   }And whenever you want to exit application - just set running variable to false, and free the allocated memory after while loop.
   ```
3. Or you can do nothing - any modern OS correctly deallocates all the allocated memory when process terminates. Of course, if you need do some special thing on termination - like write to log file, send network packets, then you must manually do that.

Comment: In method 2, what if I close the window. Will I fall in an infinite `while` loop? Need any other condition?

Answer (score 2):

Register an exit function with **atexit(onexit)** before the main loop.